# Encrypt Passwords in PHP before sending through the url via GET

Tags: php

I have a form where I have a password field. When the users submits the form, all the fields including the passwords are clearly visible in the url when they passes through the URL to another php page. Is there any way to avoid this ? I dont want the password to be visible.

Comment: You don't want to do it with GET, you want POST and SSL.

Comment: @Deva, The above comment is a MUST

Comment: **You really *don't* want to be encrypting passwords.** You need to **hash** them, so passwords cannot be retrieved if the database is hacked. Transmission on the other hand, should use SSL & POST.

Comment: To add to what @bob said, the first rule in security is don't bother with security, use the secure systems designed by other more knowledgeable people.

Answer (score 6):

You should be `POST`ing the form data rather than using the `GET` method to remove the data from the query-string :

```
<form method="post" ...
```

And encrypting the data using [SSL](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/security/article.php/3774876/Setting-Up-a-Secure-SSL-Connection.htm) - that way all the data will be sent securely.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) eloquently explains the difference between `POST` and `GET`.

Comment: Should also probably mention that passwords should be hashed, and not encrypted, when stored in a database.

Comment: @bob Yes and no; in this instance we're talking about sending data to the server rather than storing anything, therefore encryption is sufficient. However I agree that OP should note that [hashing](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure) is required when storing passwords.

Comment: @bob kinda off topic in this question, but a good mention none the less. You definitely want to encrypt the password from the client to the server (SSL), and then hash it if you're going to persist it.